# JS error uploading images in Editor

Tags: devdemon, editor, redactor

After moving my site to a secure server (SSL), uploading images via the Editor fieldtype by uploading a new file throws an javascript error, traced to the Redactor javascript file.

If I first choose an existing image, everything works fine and I can embed the image. If I first try to upload a new image and that fails, then I try to choose an existing image as before, existing images no longer works unlike if I do it right away.

Error Messages from console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of nullredactor.min.js?v=3.2.4:4 Redactor.fn.$.Redactor.uploadLoadedjquery.js?v=1421706349:16 s.extend.proxy.ojquery.js?v=1421706349:17 H.event.dispatchjquery.js?v=1421706349:16 H.event.add.a.handle.s`

Answer (score 0):

Most often these errors are caused by cross-domain ajax. Did you update URL in the general configuration to have the same https url? Since Redactor uses AJAX to upload the image, any difference in the domain will break it.

[image]

Comment: Yes, all addresses have been changed to the https address.